Google sheets - transpose & formatting a list of names/dates/times into into a schedule-style format
I have data coming from an app that exports to Sheets in this format, & trying to get a formula to reformat it:
EmployeeName    ShiftDate   Store   ShiftStart  ShiftEnd
Person person   22/04/24    Our Store
Person person   23/04/24    Our Store
Person person   24/04/24    Our Store
Person person   25/04/24    Our Store
Person person   26/04/24    Our Store
Person person   27/04/24    Our Store   2024-04-27 16:00:00 2024-04-28 0:00:00
Person person   28/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonB  22/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonB  23/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonB  24/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonB  25/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonB  26/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonB  27/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonB  28/04/24    Our Store   2024-04-28 16:00:00 2024-04-29 0:00:00
Person PersonC  22/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonC  23/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonC  24/04/24    Our Store   2024-04-24 16:15:00 2024-04-25 0:00:00
Person PersonC  25/04/24    Our Store   2024-04-25 16:15:00 2024-04-26 0:00:00
Person PersonC  26/04/24    Our Store
Person PersonC  27/04/24    Our Store   2024-04-27 15:15:00 2024-04-28 0:00:00
Person PersonC  28/04/24    Our Store   2024-04-28 15:15:00 2024-04-29 0:00:00
...
Here is how I'd like it to look (Note, the Shift Date column shows day/month/year, but the shift start & end shows the date formatted as year-month-date.   Also, in the original the words "EmployeeName" are combined, & I'd like to separate them in the formatted version):
Employee Name   Monday, April 22, 2024  Tuesday, April 23, 2024 Wednesday, April 24, 2024   Thursday, April 25, 2024    Friday, April 26, 2024  Saturday, April 27, 2024    Sunday, April 28, 2024
Person person                       4:00 PM
12:00 AM
Person PersonB                          4:00 PM
12:00 AM
Person PersonC      4:15 PM 4:15 PM     3:15 PM 3:15 PM
12:00 AM    12:00 AM        12:00 AM    12:00 AM
Person PersonD                  4:15 PM     6:45 AM
12:00 AM        3:15 PM
Tried a combination of query & transpose commands, but I'm not quite skilled enough to get it working to format it anywhere near what I need.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HebNC-MyLlPjFPmZ_lKth4aIBnJ_rDSKbBl2xIXiU_8/edit#gid=2100307022

I have 2 formatted sheets in there - the first is my ideal layout, the 2nd is an alternate that will work ok also.


You may try:
=let(Σ,tocol(,1), Λ,unique(torow(Data!B2:B,1),1), reduce(Σ,unique(tocol(Data!C2:C,1)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(if(iserror(a&""),Σ,a),c,hstack("Employee Name",Λ),
 reduce(Σ,unique(filter(Data!A:A,Data!C:C=c)),lambda(f,q,vstack(f,hstack(q,map(Λ,lambda(y,index(let(z,tocol(xlookup(q&y,Data!A:A&Data!B:B,Data!D:E)),if(z="",,text(z,"HH:MM AM/PM")))))))))),)))))



that got it most of the way - Thank you!   The date column headers are still not formatted as "ddd, m/d/yy".  Also, is there any way to have the formula change the text on the header rows to bold?

Date supplied in column B is not a real date format which can be formatted. Test it with isdate() & it will return false. Use conditional format rules to bold the headers(just like the added auto header colors)
